# List all tasks of a VM using govc cli

Tags: go, virtual-machine, vmware, vsphere

I am trying to find a way to display all the tasks of a specific VM using govc cli.
I am using this command: `govc tasks vm-name` but it only lists the recent tasks and not the tasks occurred in the past.

Is there any way to do so?